# Anychart - Deselected legend item color

Tags: anychart

How can I change the color of items in the legend when they are turned off? Right now I know how to do is change the color of a series, which then changes the color of the items on the legend (but only while they are not switched off). I also know how to permanently change the color of legend items, but I don't know how to choose the color that they change to when turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this setting is not available via API directly, but you can use this workaround:

1. clone the rep: https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart/
2. change the settings here:
   https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart/blob/master/src/core/ui/LegendItem.js#L66-L73
3. build the js:
       https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart/#build-and-debug

Comment: Thank you so much!